# How to create an MVC form using MongoDB, Node.js(+express) and Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I've been tasked with creating a simple CRUD app using the above stack.

However, my lack of knowledge with it might be preventing me from doing things in an easier fashion.

My main concern is with Updates.  I have an object (document) that is loaded from the database. The fields need to be mapped into a form, and when the form contents are modified and saved, the database must be updated.

I found it very easy to render, and populate the form dynamically using JADE, however, on the way back, I find myself rebuilding the object "manually" by sending a stringified JSON representation of the form using jQuery; before storing it back into the database.

Is there some automatic tool that performs this mapping for me?
Given a JSON object and a form, it will handle the population and saving of information back into the model.

For reference, I'm coming from a SpringMVC+Hibernate background.

Pointers to a tutorial or even a simple example would be fine.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb) helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others, I would definitely recommend [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/).  It helped me when I was starting off trying to learn a similar stack.  On the server you might have something like this:

```
// Define schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    { name: 'string',
      description: 'string',
      email: 'string',
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    });

// Instantiate db model
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// POST from client
exports.addUser = function (req, res) {

    // req.body contains the json from the client post
    // as long as the json field names are the same as the schema field names it will map the data automatically
    var newUser = new User(req.body); 

    newUser.save(function (err) {
      if(err) {
          return res.json({error: "Error saving new user"});
      } else {
        console.log("success adding new user");
        res.json(newUser);
      }

    });
};

// PUT from client
exports.updateUser = function(req, body) {
    // this contains the updated user json
    var updatedUser = req.body;

    // here we lookup that user by the email field
    User.findOne({ 'email': updatedUser.email }, function (err, user) {
      if(err) {
        return res.json({error: "Error fetching user" });
      }
      else {
        // we succesfully found the user in the database, update individual fields:
        user.name = updatedUser.name;
        user.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return res.json({error: "Error updating user"});
            } else {
                console.log("success updating user");
                res.json(updatedUser);
            }
        })
      }
    });

};
```

Edit* Apparently Mongoose actually has a findOneAndUpdate method which essentially does the same thing as I wrote out above for updating a model.  You can read about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for:

    var newUser = new User(req.body); 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [`LocomotiveJS`](http://locomotivejs.org/), by the creator of [`Passport`](http://passportjs.org/).

Locomotive has Mongoose ORM [support](http://locomotivejs.org/guide/mongoose/).
You modify your local JS object and call save() for update.
Does this fit your needs?

Here's a sample using this setup for a blog:
https://github.com/strongloop/sample-blog

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I'll definitely be using locomotive in the future

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't construct the JSON object in the client side using jQuery. It is better to leave that implementation to the server side. You can easily make a json object from the post variables and save the object. Also, I don't know if you need this, but mongoose is a good ODM (object document mapper) which helps you make models of collection documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try [express-orm-mvc](https://github.com/ddo/express-orm-mvc)
A simple package that support express and orm with mvc template